# CRM solution import Error while importing workflow

Tags: dynamics-crm, crm, dynamics-crm-online

I'm using **CRM 2016**, I have solution has many resources and entities, while import unmanaged solution to other CRM Org, I got error on process (name: Delete MEW) workflow ( this process doing changes on values from other entity), error as shown in log trace

> Error while importing workflow {9b58220a-6706-4765-b2c0-86e7381064a8}
>   name Delete  WEM
>
> Error Number: 0x80040216
>
> Error Message: Error while importing workflow
>   {9b58220a-6706-4765-b2c0-86e7381064a8} name Delete  WEM
>
> Error Details: Error while importing workflow
>   {9b58220a-6706-4765-b2c0-86e7381064a8} name Delete  WEM
>
> Source File: Not available
>
> Line Number: Not available
>
> Request URL:
>
> Stack Trace Info: [CrmException: Error while importing workflow
>   {9b58220a-6706-4765-b2c0-86e7381064a8} name Delete  WEM]    at
>   Microsoft.Crm.Application.Platform.ServiceCommands.PlatformCommand.XrmExecuteInternal()

I tried to add it to another new solution, it give me the same issue.

Comment: Does this workflow already exist in the target organization? If so, a quick workaround could be, to delete the workflow in the target org to get around the failing update.

Comment: The solution is probably broken, the same happened to me. I had to move over the customizations in chunks (through a bunch of temporary solutions).I have never again been able to export/import the "big" one between the environments...